# jQuery how to add index number dynamically to a table

Tags: jquery, html-table, auto-increment

I have created a table and I can add and remove rows using jQuery when a checkbox is checked. My question here is, how can I add an index number at the first column dynamically?

My table:

```
   <div>
       <table class="config" id="status_table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4"; style= "padding-bottom: 20px; color:#6666FF; text-align:left; font-size: 1.5em">Output Status</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Index</th>
                    <th>Output Type</th>
                    <th>Output Number</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td >1</td>
                    <td ><p id="type_row_one"></p></td>
                    <td ><p id="number_row_one"></p></td>
                    <td>
                        <img class="image" id = "off" style="margin-left:20px" src="static/OffLamp-icon.png" >
                        <img class="image" id = "on" style="margin-left:20px" src="static/OnLamp-icon.png" >
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>       
       </table>                     
    </div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('#outputCB').change(function(){
                   if($('#outputCB_1').is(':checked')){
                       $('#status_table tr:last').after('<tr id="output_newrow_1"><td>index+1</td><td>testing</td></tr>');}
                    else{
                        $('#status_table').find("#output_newrow_1").remove();
                    }

                });
```

So instead of `"index+1"` I want it to be able to increment from the previous index number, and decrease if the row is removed. 
How should I go about doing it? Can I assign a variable and ++1 or --1 at the Javascript? I don't really know where to start....

UPDATE:
I tried this but failed:

```
  var index=1;
           $('#outputCB').change(function(){
               if($('#outputCB_1' ||'#outputCB_2').is(':checked')){
                   index++;
                   $('#status_table tr:last').after('<tr id="output_newrow_'+index+'"><td>'+index+'</td><td id="type_row_'+index+'">type_row_'+index+'</td><td id="num_row_'+index+'">num row '+index+'</td><td><img class="image" src="static/OffLamp-icon.png" style="height:64px; width=64px"/></td></tr>');
                   }
                else{
                    index--;
                    $('#status_table').find("#output_newrow_'+index+'").remove();
                }

            });
```

it will never remove anything and it added 2 rows at a time when #outputCB_1 is checked again. :/ Why so? (sorry this is too long for a comment.)

Comment: can't find the last tr?

Answer (score 1):

just invoke this code everytime you add or delete the row

```
function updateIndex() 
{ 
    $("#status_table tr").each(function(){
      $( this ).find( "td" ).first().html( $(this).index() + 1 );
    });
}
```

Comment: can you plz explain what is `$(this)` in your `html` function `tr or td`, i guess its td and every `td` in the tr first is `1` so all the first `td` will output `1`.

Comment: another suggestion to you is to use `$(this).closest('tr').index()` this will output the tr's index

Comment: @Jai It is tr, and then I am entering the value in first td by doing filter on tr's children

Comment: it seems td because you used `find()` method and your current object is td not tr i guess.

Comment: `$(this)` correspond to the current `tr` of the loop on which `find('td').first()` returns the first `td` of that row, and the `index` of that row is set as the value of that `td`.

Comment: Yes, after find(), you will get td. I have put it in a fiddle here

Comment: Thanks guys. Do you mean after i add/remove, i can just put updateIndex() below it? As for the function, i will include in the javascript right? and do i need to initialize the index or create a variable somewhere?

Comment: @yvonnezoe Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: Question: is there a way to ignore <tr><th> lines? This code counts not only <tr><td>, but also a <th>. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/Etu9r/1/)

```
        $(function(){
            $('#outputCB').change(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    var index = $('#status_table tbody tr').length + 1
                    $('#status_table tr:last').after('<tr id="output_newrow_1"><td>'+index+'</td><td>testing</td></tr>');
                } else {
                    $('#status_table').find("#output_newrow_1").remove();
                }

            });
        })
```

Comment: thanks guys @qais and @rajesh! but i couldn't be possibly making a function for all output i have.. (i have 96 outputs and there are other similar things...) i'm thinking of using an text input instead of checkbox now... so i will have an Add and a Remove buttons. Will it be easier? i also need to post that number that user input to be displayed.i did it in a simple way by assigning ID to each, get value and display on the table. is there a simpler way?

Comment: you can do it in single function by using class instead of id

Comment: sorry.. but i do not understand :(

Answer (score 0):

If you ever want to skip <th> rows from the counter being incremented:

```
var th_rows_counter = 0;
var all_rows_counter = 0;
$("#icontable tr").each(function() {
    all_rows_counter++;
    $( this ).find( "td" ).first().html( all_rows_counter - th_rows_counter ); // replace <td> content with the counter
    $( this ).find( "th" ).first().each(function(){th_rows_counter++;}); // increment the counter of <th> rows
});
```

or for skipping <td> with different css style you can use not() function: $( this ).find( "td" ).not(".otherstyle").